# add the full URL in rich text embed image src in Wagtail API V2

Tags: python, django, api, wagtail, wagtail-apiv2

Hope you all are doing well.
Is there any way to add the full URL in embed image src in API?
Here is the API sample

```
"content": [
                {
                    "type": "full_richtext",
                    "value": "<p data-block-key=\"11dr5\"> Example: The database consists of information about a set of</p><p data-block-key=\"4l7vp\"></p><img alt=\"image-325682-1594637051\" class=\"richtext-image full-width\" height=\"410\" src=\"/media/images/image-325682-1594637051.width-800.jpg\" width=\"728\"><p data-block-key=\"b41bt\"></p><p data-block-key=\"eorjk\"> customers and accounts and the relationship between them) </p>",
                    "id": "f21e7928-f81c-477a-ab42-ba3bc2cd9226"
                }
            ]
```

how I can add this type of URL like in that `src=\"example.com/media/images/imagename\"`?

Here is my `models.py` file.

```
"""Blog listing and blog detail pages."""
from django.db import models
from modelcluster.fields import ParentalManyToManyField
from django import forms
from wagtail.admin.edit_handlers import FieldPanel, StreamFieldPanel, MultiFieldPanel, InlinePanel

from wagtail.core.fields import StreamField

from wagtail.images.edit_handlers import ImageChooserPanel

from wagtail.core.models import Page
from wagtail.snippets.models import register_snippet

# from . import blocks
from . import blocks
from .blocks import InlineVideoBlock
from rest_framework import fields, serializers

from modelcluster.fields import ParentalKey
from wagtail.api import APIField
from modelcluster.contrib.taggit import ClusterTaggableManager
from taggit.models import TaggedItemBase
from django.shortcuts import render
from wagtail.contrib.routable_page.models import RoutablePageMixin, route
#added by fathi
from rest_framework.fields import Field

@register_snippet
class BlogCategory(models.Model):
    """Blog category for a snippet."""

    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    slug = models.SlugField(
        verbose_name="slug",
        allow_unicode=True,
        max_length=255,
        help_text='A slug to identify posts by this category',
    )

    panels = [
        FieldPanel("name"),
        FieldPanel("slug"),
    ]

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Blog Category"
        verbose_name_plural = "categories"
        ordering = ["name"]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class CreateNewPage(RoutablePageMixin, Page):
    """Listing page lists all the Blog Detail Pages."""

    # template = "blog/create_new_page.html"

    custom_title = models.CharField(
        max_length=100,
        blank=False,
        null=False,
        help_text='Overwrites the default title',
    )

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        FieldPanel("custom_title"),
    ]

    def get_context(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        """Adding custom stuff to our context."""
        context = super().get_context(request, *args, **kwargs)
        context["posts"] = AddStory.objects.live().public()
        context["categories"] = BlogCategory.objects.all()

        all_posts = AddStory.objects.live().public().order_by('-first_published_at')
        if request.GET.get('tag', None):
            tags = request.GET.get('tag')
            all_posts = all_posts.filter(tags__slug__in=[tags])

        context["posts"] = all_posts
        return context

    @route(r"^category/(?P<cat_slug>[-\w]*)/$", name="category_view")
    def category_view(self, request, cat_slug):
        """Find blog posts based on a category."""
        context = self.get_context(request)

        try:
            # Look for the blog category by its slug.
            category = BlogCategory.objects.get(slug=cat_slug)
        except Exception:
            # Blog category doesnt exist (ie /blog/category/missing-category/)
            # Redirect to self.url, return a 404.. that's up to you!
            category = None

        if category is None:
            # This is an additional check.
            # If the category is None, do something. Maybe default to a particular category.
            # Or redirect the user to /blog/ ¯\_(ツ)_/¯
            pass

        context["posts"] = AddStory.objects.live().public().filter(categories__in=[category])

        # Note: The below template (latest_posts.html) will need to be adjusted
        return render(request, "blog/latest_posts.html", context)

    @route(r'^latest/?$', name="latest_posts")
    def latest_blog_posts_only_shows_last_5(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        context = self.get_context(request, *args, **kwargs)
        context["posts"] = context["posts"][:10]
        return render(request, "blog/latest_posts.html", context)


class BlogPageTag(TaggedItemBase):
    content_object = ParentalKey(
        'AddStory',
        related_name='tagged_items',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )


class AddStory(Page):
    """Blog detail page."""

    custom_title = models.CharField(
        max_length=100,
        blank=False,
        null=False,
        help_text='Overwrites the default title',
    )
    blog_image = models.ForeignKey(
        "wagtailimages.Image",
        blank=False,
        null=True,
        related_name="+",
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
    )
    categories = ParentalManyToManyField("blog.BlogCategory", blank=True)
    content = StreamField(
        [

            ("full_richtext", blocks.RichtextBlock()),
            ("simple_richtext", blocks.SimpleRichtextBlock()),
            ("Add_video", blocks.VideoRichtextBlock()),
            ('video', InlineVideoBlock()),

        ],
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )
#exposing custom field in API
    api_fields = [
        # APIField("blog_authors"),
        # Exposed StreamFields
        APIField("blog_image"),
        APIField("content"),
        APIField("categories", serializer=serializers.ListSerializer(child=fields.CharField())),
        APIField("tags"),
    ]
    content2 = StreamField(
        [

            ("full_richtext", blocks.RichtextBlock()),

        ],
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )

    tags = ClusterTaggableManager(through=BlogPageTag, blank=True)

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        FieldPanel("custom_title"),
        ImageChooserPanel("blog_image"),
        StreamFieldPanel("content"),
        FieldPanel('tags'),
        MultiFieldPanel(
            [
                FieldPanel("categories", widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple),

            ],
            heading="Categories"
        ),

    ]


class VideoBlogPage(AddStory):
    """A video subclassed page."""

    template = "blog/video_blog_page.html"

    youtube_video_id = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        FieldPanel("custom_title"),
        ImageChooserPanel("blog_image"),
        # MultiFieldPanel(
        #     [
        #         InlinePanel("blog_authors", label="Author", min_num=1, max_num=4)
        #     ],
        #     heading="Author(s)"
        # ),
        MultiFieldPanel(
            [
                FieldPanel("categories", widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple)
            ],
            heading="Categories"
        ),
        FieldPanel("youtube_video_id"),
        StreamFieldPanel("content2"),

    ]
```

I have searched many places and looked this tutorial but it didn't worked. https://learnwagtail.com/tutorials/headless-cms-serializing-richtext-blocks/

Answer (score 0):

You can add a serializer. Then in the APIField add this as your serializer.

```
from rest_framework.fields import Field


class ImageSerializerField(Field):
    def to_representation(self, value):
        return {
            "url": value.file.url,
            "title": value.title,
            "width": value.width,
            "height": value.height,
        }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).